# how to start celery periodic task at 9:30 to 12:30 every 30 seconds?

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to run a celery task in Django from 09:30 to 12:30 for every 30 seconds.
Is it possible to turn the interval on for 30 seconds and turn on the interval schedule only for a certain period of the day?

Comment: cron does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, so, the ***every 30 seconds*** seems not going to work

Comment: so you can do time.sleep(30) and run it again ;); or less than 30,if it runs more than a second for example